# Send vector as parameter in Java

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

This may be a silly problem. I believe it's preety clear what I want to achieve, but I can't think of the syntax for it. Suppose I have:

```
public void foo(int[] v){

}
public static void main(String args[]){
     foo({1, 2, 3});
}
```

Can I call foo without declaring a new array? If yes, how ?

Comment: You must declare a new array.  You do not have to assign it to a variable.

Comment: This seems to work. Silly me I haven't tried foo(new int[]{1, 2, 3});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't compile the way you wrote it. But this will, and maybe it's what you want:

```
public void foo(int... v) {
    // ...
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
     foo(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Here, the values passed to `foo` will be automatically converted to an array. The value of `v` will be in fact an `int[]`.

Alternatively, preserving the original signature of `foo`,
you could have written this way:

```
public void foo(int[] v) {
    // ...
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
     int[] params = {1, 2, 3};
     foo(params);
}
```

It is not possible to combine those two lines otherwise into `foo({1, 2, 3})` as you wrote.

Or you could write this way:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
     foo(new int[]{1, 2, 3});
}
```

The `int...` syntax I wrote in the first version is called "varargs",
if you want to read more about it.
As you are a beginner, I don't recommend to use it,
as you may experience some pitfalls,
and it may be more confusing than useful.
Stick to the second or third versions for now.